# Metro C# StreamSocket DataReader InputStream await

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, async-await, datareader

I have a server running on my laptop and am trying to use StreamSocket to communicate with it. Everything is working fine. I can send and receive messages but I have one big question.

```
var reader = new DataReader(clientSocket.InputStream) {InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial};
Thread.Sleep(1000);
var actualLength = await reader.LoadAsync(33554432); // Buffer of 32 MB
```

In this section of my code I have to use Thread.Sleep(1000) in order for my DataReader to fill itself up and move on with the next parts. If I remove the sleep my app crashes. I need to wait on the inputstream to finish filling the DataReader, which I have no clue how long it will always take, I just chose 1000 in the sleep as an arbitrary number.

Is there any way for me to make this task wait until the inputstream finishes filing the reader? Otherwise it stops working on the LoadAsync line. I tried to do Task.FromResult and await the reader line but it didn't work(Not 100% sure I did it right, so if that should have worked, let me know.) I just don't want to do a thread sleep for a full second every time I receive a response from the server(happens a lot.)

Also, I'm not 100% sure that the problem is this, I just did some debugging, it was crashing on the actualLength line, so I put the sleep in just to test and it worked. So I assumed that was the problem...

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Exception/CallStack

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke() Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority)    Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(object context)  Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(object[] args)   Unknown
System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll!System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(System.IntPtr pHandle, int nParamCount, System.Windows.Hosting.NativeMethods.ScriptParam* pParams, System.Windows.Hosting.NativeMethods.ScriptParam* pResult)   Unknown
```

Comment: Could you post the exception with call stack?

Comment: I can't seem to get much from it. I'l post everything I see in an edit above. But that was part of why this has been so frustrating, I don't know how to see what is going wrong here.

Comment: Any `InnerException`? Why do you say this is crashing on `actualLength`? Is the code you posted run on the UI thread?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new to a lot of this and not sure how to see InnerException. The code posted is ran async, I just said it crashes on actualLength, because when I stepped through debugging, it was on that line that it bombs out. Like I said though I'm not 100% sure if it is the problem, I'm starting to wonder if the UI thread is wanting something faster than what the async thread can give it?

Comment: Do you check that socket is ready before doing your `reader.LoadAsync(33554432)` ?